# add 'publish metabox' to Gravity forms edit page/form area

Tags: php, metabox, plugin-gravity-forms

[image]

I am trying to add the same 'Publish Metabox' that is on top right sidebar of normal Wordpress posts and pages. Any thoughts?

I just tried adding this'`add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', null, 'side', 'core' );` '; but nothing appeared...

```
<!-- begin add button boxes -->
                    <ul id="sidebarmenu1" class="menu collapsible expandfirst">

                        <?php

                        add_meta_box( 'submitdiv', __( 'Publish' ), 'post_submit_meta_box', null, 'side', 'core' );
```

Answer (score 0):

Gravity Forms aren't a post type, so it doesn't display actual meta boxes. Even if you managed to add the meta box, it wouldn't be functional, because the form isn't a post.